# IF loop to check if file exists in VBS

Tags: vbscript, boolean

I'm doing a lab, and the instructions say to check if a file exists. It suggests using the boolean `Not` to do it.

Here's my code, but no matter what I do, I can't get past the end of the loop. I keep getting the error message that says the file doesn't exist.

```
Const Read = 1, Write = 2, Append = 8, ASCII = 0

FileName  = "C:\users\gryphon\IP_Addresses.csv"
ipAddrStr = ""
NewRoom   = 106
Comp1_IP  = "192.168.10.59"
Comp2_IP  = "192.168.10.60"
Comp3_IP  = "192.168.10.61"
Comp4_IP  = "192.168.10.61"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

ipAddrStr = CStr(NewRoom) & "1," & CStr(Comp1_IP) & CStr(NewRoom) & "2," & _
            CStr(Comp2_IP) & CStr(NewRoom) & "3," & CStr(Comp3_IP) & _
            CStr(NewRoom) & "4," & CStr(Comp4_IP)

If Not fso.FileExists("FileName") Then
  WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(Chr(7) & Chr(7))
  WScript.Echo "File Does Not Exist." & vbCrLf & _
    "You Must Create the File Before You can Read the File."
  WScript.Quit
End If
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it? This has to be done by 04DEC2016 at 11PM PST. I asked my instructor for help last Monday, and I'm still waiting to hear back.

Comment: Remove quotes from `"FileName"` you want to check the existence of the string path in the variable `FileName` not the literal string "FileName". So line should read `If Not so.FileExists(FileName) Then`. Also what's this about the *"end of the loop"*?, there is no loop in your code.

Comment: If your instructor has not explained the difference between variables and string literals by now, you should get a new instructor.

Answer (score 0):

remove the double quotes from fso.fileExists("FileName"),because of that it is taking the string Filename instead of the value of Filename variable

```
If  NOT fso.FileExists(FileName) Then
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(Chr(7) & chr(7))
WScript.Echo "File Does Not Exist." & vbcrlf & _
"You Must Create the File Before You can Read the File."
WScript.Quit
End If
```

Comment: It's a simple typo and likely the question will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Lankymart My 'close, offtopic, typo' flag was disputed, so maybe not.

Comment: This was a huge help, thanks, and yes, I'm getting a new instructor. Almost half the class is failing because it's an online course, and the instructor apparently assumes that we're all experienced scripters and coders. That it's an INTRO to scripting class is apparently beside the point.                                                                                                                How do I mark this as closed?